# PHP Queue stops working with Twilio invalid phone number

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, sms

I am sending bulk email with Twilio using PHP/Laravel. I can't use Twilio notify because every phone number will use different text. Everything works fine if all phone numbers are valid, but if any invalid phone number occurs my queue stopped with error. Try catch block or failed function didn't work at all

My code:

```
 public function handle()
    {
        $message = $this->client->messages->create(
            $this->number,
            [
                'from' => $this->from,
                'body' => $this->msg
            ]
        );
    }
```

(I have tried wrapping above function code inside try catch block also, but no luck)
Then I tried adding failed function

```
public function failed(\Exception $exception)
    {
        // Send user notification of failure, etc...
    }
```

Still no luck.

I am getting following error:

```
array:4 [
  "code" => 21211
  "message" => "The 'To' number  is not a valid phone number."
  "more_info" => "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211"
  "status" => 400
]
```

And i am using following queue command

```
php artisan queue:work  --sleep=3 --tries=3 &
```

After getting Twilio error, If i stop command and run 2 more times, then only failed sms moved into failed_jobs table and execution continue to next jobs. Using laravel 7.x

Any help highly appreciated.

================================

Here is complete job

```
class BulkSms implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    private $number;
    private $msg;
    private $client;
    private $from;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($number, $from, $msg, $client)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
        $this->from = $from;
        $this->msg = $msg;
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $message = $this->client->messages->create(
            $this->number,
            [
                'from' => $this->from,
                'body' => $this->msg
            ]
        );
    }

    public function failed(\Exception $exception)
    {
        // Send user notification of failure, etc...
    }
}
```

Above is called from controller something like

```
foreach ($candidateSMS as $number) { 
    BulkSms::dispatch($mobile, $this->from, $msgBody, $client)->delay(now()->addSecond(.2));
}
```

Comment: are you actively restarting your queue with `queue:restart` after each change ? Are you handling sending all messages in a single job ? could you share your complete job ?

Comment: @Ersoy I have added my code. Thanks

Comment: @Ersoy I have updated my main question

Comment: as far as i see, you are sending messages one by one - one fail shouldn't affect other one - depending on your laravel version, you need to add `daemon` option to your  `php artisan queue:work --tries=3 --sleep=3` command (probably use superviosor or nohup to control all these processes)

Comment: Thanks @Ersoy. I have tried daemon, nohup and supervisor also, still queue stuck on first invalid number.
nohup php artisan queue:work  --sleep=3 --tries=3 &

Comment: which queue driver are you using

Comment: I am using database driver

'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

Comment: could you try `redis` with multiple `queue:work` - it shouldn't block each other. i am not familiar with database queue driver - but i am using redis in production for processing more than 1 billion/day.

Comment: Thanks @Ersoy, will surely try redis and will confirm. Thanks again